# Does neo4j MATCH then filter or filter then MATCH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I run the query

```
MATCH paths=(l:Left)-[:CONNECTED_TO*..5]->(r:Right)
WHERE (l.id IN $left_ids) AND (r.id IN $right_ids)
RETURN paths
```

ie, give me all `paths` with `Left` connected to `Right` so long as left is in `left_ids` and right is in `right_ids`.

Should I expect neo4j to

1. perform the cartesian product of `Left` and `Right`, and *then* filter the results - or
2. does it only search for paths once it has worked out which nodes are allowed?

Also - is there any obvious way for me to search this out for myself - ie is there a query planner, or some good meaty documentation that I've missed?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in the [Profiling](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) chapter of Neo4j docs:

> **EXPLAIN**
>
> If you want to see the execution plan but not run the statement,
>   prepend your Cypher statement with EXPLAIN. The statement will always
>   return an empty result and make no changes to the database.
>
> **PROFILE**
>
> If you want to run the statement and see which operators are doing
>   most of the work, use PROFILE. This will run your statement and keep
>   track of how many rows pass through each operator, and how much each
>   operator needs to interact with the storage layer to retrieve the
>   necessary data. Please note that profiling your query uses more
>   resources, so you should not profile unless you are actively working
>   on a query.

So you can prepend your queries with `PROFILE` or `EXPLAIN` and see the [execution plan](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/execution-plans/) generated by Neo4j. This way:

```
PROFILE MATCH paths=(l:Left)-[:CONNECTED_TO*..5]->(r:Right)
WHERE (l.id IN $left_ids) AND (r.id IN $right_ids)
RETURN paths
```

Comment: Hi @danodonovan, you are welcome. This solved your issue? If so, please, consider accepting it as the right answer. Otherwise, let me know. Then I can try help you again.